# adding location filter at runtime using twitter4j

Tags: java, twitter, twitter-hbc

I'm using twitter4j to get a stream filtered by location from twitter, using the folowing :

```
    List<Location> locations = new ArrayList<>;

    StatusesFilterEndpoint endpoint.locations(locations);
    BasicClient client = new ClientBuilder()
            .name(NAME)
            .hosts(Constants.STREAM_HOST)
            .endpoint(endpoint)
            .authentication(auth)
            .processor(new StringDelimitedProcessor(rowTweet))
            .build(); 
   client.connect();


   while (isConnected()) {
                String rowtweet = rowTweet.poll(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                if (rowtweet != null) {
                    Status status = DataObjectFactory.createStatus(rowtweet);
                    statusQueue.put(status);
                }
            }
```

this is working fine and filter the status based on the location and I got the status from this locations, but what I need to removed or add location at runtime, is that possible ?

I tried to add the location using, but it is given the following exception :

```
 public void addLocation(Location target) throws InterruptedException, TwitterException        {
    locations.add(target);
    endpoint.locations(locations);
    connect();
}
```

this exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is already a connection thread running for TweetsByLocationStream, endpoint: /1.1/statuses/filter.json?delimited=length&stall_warnings=true
        at com.twitter.hbc.httpclient.BasicClient.connect(BasicClient.java:98)
        at com.newsry.streams.TweetsByLocationStream.connect(TweetsByLocationStream.java:77)
        at com.newsry.streams.TweetsByLocationStream.addLocation(TweetsByLocationStream.java:129)
        at com.newsry.engine.NewsryEngine.addLocation(NewsryEngine.java:183)
        at com.newsry.streams.LocationStreamTest.main(LocationStreamTest.java:44)
```

Comment: Have you tried first to stop(), then to addLocation() and at last connect() or reconnect()?

Comment: thank you, but this what I already was do, stop() then addLocation() then reconnect() which is failed, I tried to add the location without stop() and it is working fine, I will replay with the correct code.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to stop the `TwitterStream` and change your `FilterQuery` by adding or removing locations that you want. Then you need to restart the `TwitterStream`. It is almost runtime but it work (it is done in very small time interval, so you wont lose `twitter4j` streaming results).